# Problems with 'Leave Empty' Last login in FOSUserBundle integration

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I am trying to bring the creation of users into easy_admin, I have followed the steps in the [documentation](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/fosuserbundle-integration.md) but I am still getting the error:

```
Expected argument of type "DateTime", "NULL" given
```

I am afraid this issue was fixed, but I can not make it work as expected. My code is the same as showed in the documentation, is there any code I am missing, I am using version 1.15.1.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the lastLogin property to new \DateTime() in your AdminController constructor.

Or you can set nullable=true overwriting the default lastLogin field in your AdminController class